# React Navigation deeplink external navigation issue

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have a simple app that implements react-navigation

```
const prefix = Platform.OS == 'android' ? 'http://test.in/' : 'http://';
const StackNav = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: MainApp },
  Detail: {
    screen: ContentDetail,
    path: 'content/:contentId',
  },
  NewsDetail: NewsDetail
});

const App = () => <StackNav uriPrefix={prefix} />;
```

But when I try to navigate to Detail screen using external link it doesn't navigate.

Tried

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.test.in/content/114" com.test
```

for navigating from command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a listener that handles the `url` event of the external navigation. Take a look at the doc: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html

```
componentDidMount() {
    Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL)
  }

  handleOpenURL = (event) => {
    somethingWithDeepLink(event.url)
  }
```

Comment: This should be `react-navigation` job, as it creates the toplevel object. There is no place to add this code.